# Elan smart pad in Asus laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, touchpad

I have an asus laptop with a elan smart pad, when the driver is not installed windows recognizes certain functions (right click, left click, middle click, scroll), when I install the elan driver, It recognizes all the functions (resize , open my pc, etc) but from time to time it only does basic functions (like de windows driver), yet the icon of elan in the taskbar shows what I'm doing ( 3 fingers click, resize, etc). And after a while regains all functions.

Someone knows what could be the problem?